# Multiple Hover & Animate Instances with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a body map with multiple trigger points on it. I'd like a unique box filled with a title and copy to show up on hover per trigger point. I've written each function out one at a time, but I'd like to write it a little cleaner and more concise. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(".point-one").hover(
function() {
    $("#patient-body").animate({opacity: 0.3});
    $(".trigger-point").animate({opacity: 0.1});
    $("#service-one").animate({opacity: 1.0});
},
function() {
    $("#patient-body").delay(100).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
    $(".trigger-point").delay(100).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
    $("#service-one").delay(100).animate({opacity: 0}, "fast");
});


$(".point-two").hover(
    function() {
        $("#patient-body").animate({opacity: 0.3});
        $(".trigger-point").animate({opacity: 0.1});
        $("#service-two").animate({opacity: 1.0});
    },
    function() {
        $("#patient-body").delay(100).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
        $(".trigger-point").delay(100).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
        $("#service-two").delay(100).animate({opacity: 0}, "fast");
    }
);
```

How can I write this more efficiently?

The HTML that accommodates this is:

```
                            <a href="#" class="trigger-point point-one">Shoulder</a>
                        <div id="service-one" class="fpt-service">
                            <h3>Shoulder</h3>
                            <p>We treat arthritis, dislocation, frozen shoulder, tendinitis, rotator cuff tears, post surgical arthroscopy, and other conditions that inhibit range of motion.</p>
                        </div>

                        <a href="#" class="trigger-point point-two">Back</a>
                        <div id="service-two" class="fpt-service">
                            <h3>Back</h3>
                            <p>Back conditions that we treat include arthritis, herniated discs, ligamentous strains, lumbar radiculopathy, rhombois and lower trapezius strain, muscular strains, osteoporosis, scoliosis, spinal stenosis, T4 syndrome and upper back stiffness.</p>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn these anonymous hover functions into named functions for simpler maintenance and combine some selectors.  Also, I assumed that each service div will follow the trigger link in the page layout so that we can use `$(this).next('div')` to reference them in the hover functions:

```
var pointIn = function (e) {
        $('#patient-body').animate({ opacity: 0.3 });
        $('.trigger-point').animate({ opacity: 0.1 });
        $(this).next('div').animate({ opacity: 1.0 });
    },
    pointOut = function (e) {
        $('#patient-body, .trigger-point').delay(100).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 'fast');
        $(this).next('div').delay(100).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 'fast');
    };

$('.point-one, .point-two').hover(pointIn, pointOut);
```

See working demo → http://jsfiddle.net/KSqeF/2/

Answer (score 0):

How about using service-1, service-2 etc ids. Then create a for loop that constructs these functions and attaches these events for you. Sort of like:

```
for (i = 0; i < number_service_points; i++) {
    $(".point-" + i).hover(
        function....
    );
```

Although I think the ideal solution is to use classes for the whole thing and DOM traversal to find the associated service information. That way you attach the .hover event to all `.points` and then use `$(this).next('div')` or something to find the associated element. That's the cleanest way in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Give the A tag a 'title' attribute which matches the 'id' of the DIV you want it to show.

Example Javascript:

```
    $(".trigger-point").hover(
function() {

    var id = $(this).attr( 'title' );

    $("#patient-body").animate({opacity: 0.3});
    $("#" + id).animate({opacity: 1.0});
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.1});

},
function() {

    var id = $(this).attr( 'title' );

    $("#patient-body").animate({opacity: 1}, "fast");
    $("#" + id).animate({opacity: 0}, "fast");
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");

});
```

Example HTML:

```
<a title="shoulder" href="#" class="trigger-point">Shoulder</a>
<div id="shoulder" class="fpt-service">
<h3>Shoulder</h3>
<p>We treat arthritis, dislocation, frozen shoulder, tendinitis, rotator cuff tears, post surgical arthroscopy, and other conditions that inhibit range of motion.</p>
</div>

<a title="back" href="#" class="trigger-point">Back</a>
<div id="back" class="fpt-service">
<h3>Back</h3>
<p>Back conditions that we treat include arthritis, herniated discs, ligamentous strains, lumbar radiculopathy, rhombois and lower trapezius strain, muscular strains, osteoporosis, scoliosis, spinal stenosis, T4 syndrome and upper back stiffness.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML consistently has the `<a>` immediately preceding the `.fpt-service` div, you may be able to handle all cases with one snippet like this:

```
$('.trigger-point').hover( function(){ // identify by class, not ID
  $('#patient-body').animate({opacity: 0.3});
  $(this)
    .animate({opacity: 0.1});
    .nextAll('.fpt-service:first') // should walk to the correct div if present
    .animate({opacity: 1.0});
}, function(){
  $('#patient-body').delay(100).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
  $(this)
    .delay(100).animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast")
    .nextAll('.fpt-service:first')
    .delay(100).animate({opacity: 0}, "fast");
});
```